# User string input. Counting characters

Tags: java, junit

My code works except I have to make it pass some Junit test. It passes all but one. It passes when the character enters nothing, enters upper case, lower case, or a mix of the two, and it works when the enter Hello World!

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] textArray = new int[26];

    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    readText(input, textArray);
}

public static void readText(Scanner input, int[]text){
    char letter = 0;

    if (input.hasNext() == false) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    else {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String a = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                letter = a.charAt(i);

                if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
                    text[letter-65] = (text[letter-65]) + 1;
                }
                else if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
                    text[(letter - 32) - 65] = (text[(letter - 32) - 65]) + 1;
                }
                else if (letter == ' ') {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    for (int y = 0; y < text.length; y++) {
        if (text[y] > 0) {
            System.out.println(alphabet[y] + ": " + text[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

The Junit tests this input: 1 2 3%n! ? >%n:) !!%n

The expected output is

```
Enter text: 
    //empty line here
```

But instead the output from my code is

```
Enter text: //with no line after
```

I'm not sure how to get the extra line after without ruining my other junit tests. I tried one way and it worked but then my Hello World didn't work properly.

And example of when its working:
When I hit run the console will say

Enter text:

I have a Scanner input so the user will enter some words and it will look like this in console

Enter text: sOme wordS

Then it will count the number of times each letter was used and print that to console like this

Enter text: sOme wordS
D: 1
E: 1
M: 1
O: 2
R: 1
S: 2
W: 1

If I don't enter anything when asked and just hit the enter key the output is

Enter text:
//empty line here

But when I enter

Enter text: 1 2 3
? ! >
:) !!

The output doesn't add an extra line at the end.

Comment: Use System.out.println("Enter text: ") instead of System.out.print("Enter text: ").

Comment: `System.out.println("Enter text: " + "\n");` You want a new line after "Enter text". If you also want to tab it, you can use `System.out.println("Enter text: " + "\n\t");`

Comment: @return0 Can't do that because user input has to be on the same line as "Enter text: "

Comment: @JaynineReturns I thought you wanted the expected output with a new line... Not sure what you mean by user input.

Comment: Where does the user input come in at this line? Before the Enter text? @JaynineReturns

`Enter text: 
    //empty line here`

Comment: @return0 I edited the post. The last section shows what the output should look like.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `System.out.println("Enter text: ");` instead of `System.out.print("Enter text: ");`

Update: After getting clarified your requirement I propose to use the following code.

```
public static void readText(Scanner input, int[]text){
        char letter = 0;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String a = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                letter = a.charAt(i);

                if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
                    text[letter-65] = (text[letter-65]) + 1;
                }
                else if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
                    text[(letter - 32) - 65] = (text[(letter - 32) - 65]) + 1;
                }
                else if (letter == ' ') {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
            }
        }

        String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        boolean emptyOutput = true;
        for (int y = 0; y < text.length; y++) {
            if (text[y] > 0) {
                System.out.println(alphabet[y] + ": " + text[y]);
                emptyOutput = false;
            }
        }
        if (emptyOutput) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tired that already. I cannot do that because then when the user enters text it will be on the line under "Enter text: " when its supposed to be on the same line.

Comment: why don't you add a
System.out.println();
 after the line that you read input 
String a = input.nextLine();

Comment: I edited the post. The last sections shows what the output should be like

Comment: The only thing you added is the code under where I declared my alphabet array correct? I'm just trying to understand how that wouldn't add an extra line for when I do enter words. It worked though thank you very much! I'm just trying understand how it did is all haha.

Comment: Oh I see now! That took me a second but I understand now. Yeah that was my problem I wasn't understanding how I can check if the amount of letters used is 0. But now I get it. That was a simple fix wow I don't know why I was blanking. Thank you so much!

Comment: it was a pleasure to help you!